# intellij doesn't recognize babelrc alias path when it import file included in that path- warning module is not install

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, babeljs, create-react-native-app

This is my babelrc file. installed module-resolver and declared root and aliases.
actually this do works!! but underline annoying me... please click images below I cannot post images cause I'm new here.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzN5O.png]
warning like this - module is not installed i think intelliJ recognize it as module..
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTcWx.png]
I changed my root "./" -> "./src" but it didn't work. 
I also installed eslint but don't know about that well I think that won't help this problem

**has anyone solved this kind of issue before?**

Answer (score 4):

IDEA provides no special support for babel-resolver; please follow [WEB-28241](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28241) for updates.

The problem is that there are dozens of plugins defining their own ways to resolve modules, we can't afford providing special support for all them... You can try using webpack aliases instead, or try a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22717#focus=streamItem-27-1558931-0-0:

- create a file `config.js` (you can use a different name if you like) in your project root dir
- define your aliases there using the following syntax:

`System.config({
      "paths": {
         "components/*": "./src/components/*"
      }
    });`

`components` here is the alias you have defined in `.babelrc`

Now you can use imports like

`import MyComponent from 'components/core/MyComponent';`

in your code

Comment: Hi Lena, I've followed your suggestion. Now, I could cmd+click on my import and navigated to files. One that bothered me, my PHPStorm could not give auto import suggestion when I typed my aliases. For example, when I typed "@the", I expect PHPStorm will give import suggestion to "@themes". Now, I have to type the entire import statement manually. Any idea to solve that?